# jQuery using delay() for Object methods

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm migrating from Prototype to jQuery, and despite numerous Googlings, I haven't found a definitive answer to how the delay() function is applied to methods within an object - in this instance, a method called "animate" within the "Banner" object.

My Prototype call:

```
Banner.animate.delay(6);
```

I've just started migrating after years of resisting switching javascript frameworks, any help in understanding the fundamental differences is of great help.

Comment: It's not clear at all what you're trying to do here, jQuery doesn't really work on objects like that, and `delay` is a method for animations only, unless you create your own queue.

Comment: In jQuery the [delay() method](http://api.jquery.com/delay) is used to affect items queued on the element, such as animations. In your example though, it would only delay for 6ms, which is not really going to be noticable. If you're looking for seconds, use a value of `6000`. That said, if you can give more details about your exact issue, we can probably be of more useful assistance.

Comment: in jQuery, `Banner.animate(function(){//animation stuff},6000);`

Comment: It's basically to change a banner image every six seconds. Prototype uses seconds, not milliseconds. I prefer to keep my function calls as methods wrapped in an object or class.

Comment: you can use "setTimeout" method for making delay